# How to change javascript code so popups open as bPopup, not in new popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting, popup, bpopup

How to change code below that popup windows open as dpopups (http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/). Now my code opens popups just in a new popup window.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#taulu').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "taulu.php",
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<button id='muokkaa'>Muokkaa</button>"
        } ]
    } );
$('#taulu tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {

        var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        var myWindow = window.open('muokkaa.php?id=' + data[0]+'&saldo='+ data[3]+'&nimi='+ data[1], "", "width=300, height=300");
    } );
}
```

So just like this above but I want popups to open as bpopup

```
$('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
    contentContainer:'.content',
    loadUrl: 'muokkaa.php?id=' + data[0]+'&saldo='+ data[3]+'&nimi='+ data[1]' //Uses jQuery.load()
});
```

This above is something from document but I can't get it work right.

[image: There is my buttons row by row style]
Picture shows my html site. I have jQuery already included. Every of those buttons should open dPopup.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#taulu').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "taulu.php",
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<button id='muokkaa'>Muokkaa</button>"
        } ]
    } );

        $('#taulu tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        var myWindow = ('muokkaa.php?id=' + data[0]+'&saldo='+ data[3]+'&nimi='+ data[1]);

    $(function ()    {
        $('<div>').dialog({
            modal: true,
            open: function ()
            {
                $(this).load(myWindow);
            },         
            height: 400,
            width: 400,
            title: 'Dynamically Loaded Page'
        });
    });
    } );
}
);
```

I just used jquery dialog, now it works.